# How to remove an entity class in a Symfony2 project

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, data-modeling

When we initially designed our project, we had a couple of entities that to date are unused (and we don't plan to implement them in the near future). Ergo I want to remove them from my project. I would proceed like this (all steps manually performed):

1. Remove all relations from my currently used entities.
2. Delete the doctrime ORM file `src/Resources/config/doctrine`
3. Delete the class PHP file from `src/Entity`
4. Remove the table from the database

What I would like to know: Are there any routines (e.g. console commands) that may support this procedure? For example, if I run

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

after having removed all relations and deleted the files, that I get the SQL statement that removes the according table(s)?

Comment: Take a look at DoctrineMigrationsBundle

Comment: @Paziツ I can't find anything which could help in my case. Can you quote or link what exactly could help?

Comment: The good practice is to not use the `schema:update`, but to only rely on migration classes, that will give you the possibility to write raw sql to align the database to your current model. The key point is that the migrations are to be written both ways: in your case, it would be the `up` command for removing the table, and the `down` command for restoring it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your steps to delete an entity are OK.

You can't remove a table from Doctrine, as Doctrine doesn't know about it. Have a look at this question:

[Deleting table using Doctrine2 and Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689226/deleting-table-using-doctrine2-and-symfony2)

Answer (score 6):

Once you have removed the entities from your code, you can use the following console command to drop the tables:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --complete --dump-sql
```

Note the use of the `--complete` option.

---

Here are the relevant parts from the `doctrine:schema:update` help text:

> **Options:**
>
> > `--complete`        If defined, all assets of the database which are not relevant to the current metadata will be dropped.
> >     [...]
>
> **Help:**
>
> > [...]
> >
> > Finally, be aware that if the `--complete` option is passed, this task will drop all database assets (e.g. tables, etc) that are *not* described by the current metadata. In other words, without this option, this task leaves untouched any "extra" tables that exist in the database, but which aren't described by any metadata.
> >
> > **Hint:** If you have a database with tables that should not be managed by the ORM, you can use a DBAL functionality to filter the tables and sequences down on a global level:
> >
> > ```
> > $config->setFilterSchemaAssetsExpression($regexp);
> > ```

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! Can you provide a link to the documentation you're quoting of? I can't find it in the Symfony or Doctrine docs.

Comment: I found this help text by running `php bin/console help doctrine:schema:update`.

Answer (score 3):

to remove the table in symfony 3 you can just run a migration and the table not in use will be dropped from the DB:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```