# Completely delete Entity from symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am learning Symfony 4 and having just followed the guide about databases and doctrine i now have a new entity `Product.php` with an associated repository `ProductRepository.php` along with a new table in the DB. I want to now remove this entity/repository and update the database accordingly.

I thought I could simply remove `Product.php` and run `php bin/console make:migration:diff`

However, nothing is getting changed.  Is there some simple list of commands to remove all refs to the entity (I can't see any changes in config files - I am using annotations) or do I have to work out which files were created/modified and then go and manually drop the table.

Comment: ```php bin/console make:migration:diff``` generates the migration comparing the db and your informations. ```php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate``` will execute the migration.

Comment: Fortunately, `php bin/console make:migration:diff` won't drop the tables that aren't in entities. Imagine you have tables not used in entities that you want to keep.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting table using Doctrine2 and Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689226/deleting-table-using-doctrine2-and-symfony2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it manually by deleting those files:

1. src/Entity/Product.php
2. src/Repository/ProductRepository.php

If you have generated CRUD for your Product entity, you must delete:

1. src/Form/ProductType.php
2. src/Controller/ProductController.php
3. templates/product (the product folder)

If you are in production env, you must run `php bin/console cache:clear` to delete the cache.

Think before updating your database schema. To update, run `php bin/console d:s:u --force` - but be aware of the implications in a prod environment.

Comment: Please do not suggest running `doctrine:schema:update` in production environment.

Comment: We don't know if he is really in production environnement! I only want to precise that  the database schema will not change even if we clear the cache :-)

Comment: But you're stating "If you are in production env (...) clear cache (...). Then run schema update" - this sounds like an advice to run these commands in production env